# How to export variables declared in .then() function

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am creating angular application with the single spa. when we integrate single spa feature with the existing angular application, it creates it's new main file and considers that while starting the application. Now, my concern is I am using some async operation and providing that while starting the app like below in the main.js file:

```
resolveAsyncServices([
    {
        provide: XYZ,
        useFactory: () => XYZ.getUserLocale()
    },
    {
        provide: ABC,
        useFactory: (ABCData: Locale) => LocaleServiceNg.getUserTimezone(ABCData),
        deps: [PQR]
    },

])
  .then((providers: Array<StaticProvider>) => {
        platformBrowserDynamic(providers)
            .bootstrapModule(AppModule);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

when single spa loads its private main file to the app it looks like below:

```
const lifecycles = singleSpaAngular({
  bootstrapFunction: singleSpaProps => {
    singleSpaPropsSubject.next(singleSpaProps);
    return platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
  },
  template: '<app-root />',
  Router,
  NgZone: NgZone,
  AnimationEngine: AnimationEngine,
});

export const bootstrap = lifecycles.bootstrap;
export const mount = lifecycles.mount;
export const unmount = lifecycles.unmount;
```

i wanted to consider my resolveAsyncServices function with the help of single spa loader file. So for that I am trying below code:

```
resolveAsyncServices([
    {
        provide: XYZ,
        useFactory: () => XYZ.getUserLocale()
    },
    {
        provide: ABC,
        useFactory: (ABCData: Locale) => LocaleServiceNg.getUserTimezone(ABCData),
        deps: [PQR]
    },

])
  .then((providers: Array<StaticProvider>) => {
       const lifecycles = singleSpaAngular({
       bootstrapFunction: singleSpaProps => {
          singleSpaPropsSubject.next(singleSpaProps);
          return platformBrowserDynamic(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule);
       },
       template: '<ct-root />',
       Router,
       NgZone: NgZone,
       AnimationEngine: AnimationEngine,
  });

  export const bootstrap = lifecycles.bootstrap;
  export const mount = lifecycles.mount;
  export const unmount = lifecycles.unmount; 
})
.catch(console.error);
```

but it is giving me errors on last export lines. So, now How do i export the methods so that it can be considered by angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot export things in a `.then()` function.  It's too late as the module exports have already been returned before the `.then()` handler ever runs.

As of the current state of node.js, exports have to be synchronous and anything in a `.then()` function is not synchronous.  Usually the solution is to export a promise or to export a function that one can call to get a promise and the caller can then use `.then()` to get the value they want from that promise.

There are people working on asynchronous module loading that will allow asynchronously retrieved exports, but that's not here yet.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 .. How do i use lifecycles method declared in the .then() function to outside world so that i can export it from outside.

Comment: @SwapnilChidrawar - As I said in my answer, you can export a promise and the caller can use `.then()` on that promise to get your values.  Or, you can export a function that returns a promise that the caller can use `.then()` on to get your values.  I repeat.  You cannot directly export values retrieved asynchronously.